# Display php in divs using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to display different divs depending on a selection from a drop down menu.

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>DDlist Div Display</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowDivArea(info) {
  var sel = document.getElementById('divArea').getElementsByTagName('div');  
  for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) { sel[i].style.display = 'none'; }
  if (info == '0') { return; }
  document.getElementById('divArea'+info).style.display = 'block';
}

</script>

<style type="text/css">
.divArea { display:none; height:100px; width:500px; border:1px solid red; }
</style>

</head>

    <body>

<select id="DDDivList" onchange="ShowDivArea(this.selectedIndex)">
  <option value="0" selected> -- Select A Design Service --</option>
  <option value="1"> QR Bookmark </option>
  <option value="2"> Twitter </option>
  <option value="3"> Ning or Tumblr </option>
  <option value="4"> Flyers </option>
  <option value="5"> Business Card or Brochure</option>
  <option value="6"> Album or Mixtape cover</option>
  <option value="7"> Other</option>
</select>

<div id="divArea">
 <div id="divArea1" class="divArea">

 <form action='code.php' method='GET'>
    <input type='text' name='myname'><br>
    <input type='submit' value='Click here'>
</form>

<?php


$name = $_GET['myname'];
if ($name)
echo "Hello, $name.";


?>


</div>
 <div id="divArea2" class="divArea">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You get the point from here on. More divs for each drop down option.

This is what I don't get:  I want to add a different php script to each div. What should code.php be?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem here. What do you mean by "different PHP script"? And why can't you just insert the respective PHP code in each div?

Comment: Because of this: <form action='code.php' method='GET'>

code.php is not the page that is loaded. I have this in a wordpress page template. Should have mentioned that .. sry. so the link is something like http://site.com/?page_id=29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is what I don't get: I want to add a different php script to each div. What should code.php be?

You could `include` it, or simple insert it inline like you are currently doing.

Also, `code.php` can be anything you want. You'll probably want it to handle `$_GET['myname']`.

If you actually want `code.php` to be included there, try this

```
include 'code.php';
```

On a security note, `echo`ing `$name` like that could leave you open to an [XSS vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), unless you escaping the `$_GET` super global of course (which is probably too much of a blanket solution).

Comment: thank you. I tried including it ... but it still displays the The requested URL /code.php was not found on this server. I ll keep working on this.